# Yandex daemon doens't sync

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, cloud-storage

I have a VPS with Ubuntu Server 14.04 installed.

I'm trying to sync a folder with Yandex-Disk but it only syncs when I start a manual sync (i.e.: `yandex-disk sync`).

But when I use `yandex-disk start` to start the daemon, no sync is made. Am I missing something here ? if it's not correctly configured how come the manual sync works ?

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

Although the FAQ says it supports symbolic links it doesn't. I used this file structure:

```
-home/user
  |-bkp
  |-cloud
      |-yandex   <-- initialy configured to sync this dir
          |-bkp  <---symbolic link to /home/usr/bkp
```

as soon as I configured it to sync /home/user/bkp directly it worked fine.